# Masking text for transparency in CSS (cross-browser, not IE-6 or lower)

Tags: html, css, masking

What I need is a black box filled with transparent text over a background image.

See this example:
[image: Example]

Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Webkit: http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/
Old IE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532982(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Are you willing to use JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no cross-browser solution yet, only webkit seems to support masks.

```
-webkit-mask-image: url(/path/to/mask.png);
```

http://trentwalton.com/2011/05/19/mask-image-text/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great guide, showing you just want you need.

http://www.silenceit.ca/2011/03/11/css-gradients-and-webkit-image-masks-on-text/

However, the solution as with all alpha masks, isnt completely cross browser compatible Im afraid!